# Prove $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{4n^2-1} = 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I want to prove that

$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{4n^2-1} = 1$

My approach is the most logical one, rewrite as follows:

$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{4n^2-1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n-1} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n+1} $

But the remaining series are both divergent so I get to a sort of "$ \infty - \infty = 1 $".

Comment: Your approach is fine. Just consider partial sums.

Comment: The idea is still correct. Take *finite* sums and see the cancellation through.

Comment: Cf. [telescoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)

Comment: a subtle idea i didn't take into consideration. thanks guys

Answer (score 5):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2r-1} - \sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2r+1}\right) $$
$\require{cancel}$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac11-
 \cancel{\frac13}+\cancel{\frac13}-\cancel{\frac15}+\cancel{\frac15}-\cdots+\cancel{\frac{1}{2n-1}} -  \frac{1}{2n+1}\right)$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n}{2n+1}$$

I'll leave it to you to take the limit

This is known as the [method of differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)

Comment: Your approach is good, but your answer needs some editing, because, as it stands, you have equated infinite series to finite series

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Was working on it. I hope its clear now?

Comment: It's good now ($+1$)

Comment: Sweet! $^{\cdot} \smile ^{ \cdot}$

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting the term,
$\color{blue}{\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{4 n^{2} - 1}\right)}=\color{black}{\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(- \frac{1}{2 \left(n + \frac{1}{2}\right)} + \frac{1}{2 \left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)}\right)\right)}$

This is the telescoping series:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(- \frac{1}{2 \left(n + \frac{1}{2}\right)} + \frac{1}{2 \left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)}\right)=\left(1-\color{green}{\frac{1}{3}}\right)+\left(\color{green}{\frac{1}{3}}-\color{red}{\frac{1}{5}}\right)+\left(\color{green}{\frac{1}{5}}-\color{red}{\frac{1}{7}}\right)+\left(\color{blue}{\frac{1}{7}}-\color{red}{\frac{1}{9}}\right)+...=1$